# What is the benefit of adding cite attribute in blockquote tag of html?

Tags: html, citations

I am learning html from w3school.com. In the blockquote tag they have added `cite` attribute. Like this,

```
<blockquote cite="http://www.worldwildlife.org/who/index.html">
    For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature.
    The world's leading conservation organization,
    WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by
    1.2 million members in the United States and
    close to 5 million globally.
</blockquote>
```

But the text renders as,

> For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally.

My question is that when the html code will be rendered in a web browser then the reader will not find the *citation*, so what is the benefit of adding it in the code?

There might be again some semantic meaning to it for example in a web browser for blind people the citation might be pronounced. That is just my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_blockquote_cite.asp:

> The cite attribute specifies the source of a quotation.
>
> Tip: It's a good habit to always add the source of a quotation, if any.
>
> The cite attribute does not render as anything special in any of the major browsers, but it can be used by search engines to get more information about the quotation.

Also refer [Correct use of Blockquote, q and cite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205159/correct-use-of-blockquote-q-and-cite) and [What is the cite attribute for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316477/what-is-the-cite-attribute-for?rq=1) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Actually I was reading from here:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_quotation_elements.asp They did not tell about search engines. Anyways Thank you.

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: Obviously yes. And perhaps my question is a duplicate. By the way could you tell any better online source than w3school for learning html?

Comment: If it does, remember to inform other users by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Noone else can do this for you.

Comment: I will if you tell me some other better online source for learning html.

Comment: I know no better learning ressource. Also this was not part of your question and has nothing to do with marking the answer.

Comment: It has because if I keep reading w3schools then I might keep asking useless duplicate questions here. Somebody told me to go for other resources http://stackoverflow.com/a/34987206/3429430

Comment: And here goes another one http://stackoverflow.com/q/34989272/3429430 That's all due to that inadequate website.